# Visuals looking weird when slicing by year. Power BI Desktop

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dax

I created relationship between Date and Premium tables.

[image]
[image]

But when Im slicing by year, the visual looks weird:

[image]

For 2016 it shows negative data, even though its not.

[image]

For 2015 it doesnt show anything...

[image]

Why it behaves like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [EffectiveDate] column in your 'Premiums' table contains dates *and* timestamps, rather than just dates. Therefore the values will not be related to any entry in the 'Dates' table. This causes the values to be displayed under "Blank" when you slice by [Year].

E.g. the EffectiveDate value `3/1/2017 11:38:00 PM` does most likely not exist in the [Date] coulmn in your 'Dates' table.

There are multiple ways to fix this. I suggest that you create a calculated date column in your 'Premiums' table like this:

```
NewDate:=DATE(YEAR([EffectiveDate]),MONTH([EffectiveDate]),DAY([EffectiveDate]))
```

You can then use the [NewDate] column for your relationship to the 'Dates' table.

Answer (score 0):

Data was retrieved for only one year. My fault.